# How to loop through an object with key and associated array and filter the array based on value presence in another array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, algorithm, react-redux

I have an object with this structure :

```js
obj = { key: array, key:array} 

other_array = [value, value, value ...]
```

I want to iterate through `obj`, check if each value in the array corresponding to each key and if a value in the array is contained in the `other_array`, then filter/remove from `obj.array`.

This is in `React.JS`

Comment: Can you add a example with some actual values and your final expected output ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, this should give you filtered object

```js
const obj = { key: [1,2,3], key2:[3,4,5], key3: [3,5,4]} 

const other_array = [5,4,3];

let result = new Object(); 
Object.entries(obj)
.filter(element =>  !element[1].every(x => other_array.includes(x)))
.forEach(element => result[element[0]] = element[1])

console.log(result)
```